# How to implement a VoiceXML Grammar Parser

Tags: voicexml

I am trying to build a Standalone VoiceXML parser which accepts the input as the example below

```
<grammar version="1.0" root="ROOT" mode="dtmf">
  <rule id="ROOT">
    <one-of>
      <item> 1 </item>
      <item> 2 </item>
      <item> 3 </item>
      <item> 4 </item>
      <item> 5 </item>
      </one-of>
  </rule>
</grammar>
```

It is easy to write a specific parser for that specific grammar specification. However, I want to have a generic solution/algorithm which can parse/interpret all possible DTMF grammar cases.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks,
-Toan.

Comment: Please recommend me what existing parser I should use. Thanks

Comment: VoiceXML is actually an XML file, so every XML parser can help to translate a it to a DOM object. The key thing here is that we need to understand the meaning of each tag in a Voice Application context. For instance, my example grammar will only accept number 1-5 pressed from your phone keyboard. And that grammar is the simplest one.

Comment: VoiceXML grammar definition is similar to a programming language. The language vocabulary is a set of XML tags. What I am looking for is something (like ANTLR or GOLD parser) that can understand the meaning of these tags in certain circumstances so that we can validate the input in a generic way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very good open source which implements a VXML interpreter. It is JVoiceXML at http://jvoicexml.sourceforge.net/

It also includes a VXML grammar validation engine. I think this is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [NuGram](http://nugram.nuecho.com/).

Answer (score 0):

[Open VXI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openvxi/) is another open source solution that has been around for a long time. A lot of major telephony vendors have used this as the basis for their IVR platforms.